# Emails in Rails--how to keep presentation code out of my models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, activerecord

For my Rails app, we developed an half home-brewed email system. We created a model called Email which then gets added to a queue to be sent (using a web service).

To create templates, we've been just mashing strings together in the model, ie:

```
Email < ActiveRecord::Base

   def self.stock_message(recipient)
     email = Email.create do |e|
       e.recipient = recipient
       e.message = String.new
       e.message << "first line <br />"
       e.message << "second line <br />"
     end 
   end

end

#to send:
e = Email.stock_message "foo@bar.baz"
```

This clearly violates MVC and really becomes a problem when I want to format strings using helper methods. How can I properly separate the view code from the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `render_to_string` method, but as it is not availble in model, you need to call it from controller:

```
# model
Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.stock_message(recipient, message)
    email = Email.create do |e|
      e.recipient = recipient
      e.message = message
    end 
  end
end

# controller
e = Email.stock_message "foo@bar.baz", render_to_string "email/my_email"
```

If you need to pass some variables to render method, then just add `:locals => {:var1 => value, :var2 => value2}`.

```
# view
first line <br />
second line <br />
```

In this example you should store views for emails in `app/views/emails/` directory.

However, as @David said, why not use mailer provided by Rails? It would be better solution.

Comment: Any tips for making #render_to_string available in the model? Thanks...really good answer btw.

Answer (score 5):

There's a [dedicated tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) on Rails website about that. In short, you can put your email templates under `views` folder and they will be treated pretty much like traditional html templates for web-browsers.

Also, from my experience, handling of emails is very inconsistent in different versions of Rails, so you may need to fumble around a little.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using "an half home-brewed email system", instead of the one provided by Rails?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html